# One to one mapping from $A(S_1)$ into $A(S_2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

> Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be two sets. Suppose there exists a one to one mapping $\phi$ of $S_1$ into $S_2$. Show that there exists an one to one mapping from $A(S_1)$ into $A(S_2)$, where $A(S)$ means the set of all one to one mappings of $S$ onto itself.

Suppose $\{\phi_1,\phi_2,....\}$ are the elements of $A(S_1)$ and $\{\phi'_1,\phi'_2,....\}$
are the elements of $A(S_2)$. I thought the way to connect them lies through $'\phi'$.

Let $F: A(S_1) \to A(S_2)$ defined by $F(\phi_i)=\phi\circ \phi_i$.

Not sure whether $ \phi\circ \phi_i=\phi'_i$??

Comment: Elements of $f\in A(S^1)$ are 1-1 functions from $f:S^1\to S^1$ and $\phi:S^1\to S^2$ is 1-1, what can you say about their composition $\phi\circ f$

Comment: @omar 
Dude if you could see that's what I have done exactly. 
I am not sure if these are exactly the isomorphisms of $A(S_2)$

Comment: I do not see why this is tagged as "abstract algebra"??? More wonder is "group theory" tag...

Comment: If the cardinality of $S_1$ is m and the card $S_2$ is n then                                                           one has to assume that $ m \leq n $.

Comment: Think about the cardinality of $A(S_1)$ and $A(S_2)$. If you do not go by the way you have defined but just map an element(map) to some element(map) will that solve your purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You want to *induce* the mapping some how.  Define $\phi^* : A(S_1) \to A(S_2)$ as $g \mapsto $ something related to $\phi$.  Well we know that $\phi \circ g$ is one-to-one and maps $S_1 \to S_2$.  What we need is a map from $S_2$ to itself though.  The only apparent option seems to be $\phi^{\leftarrow}$, which is a well-defined map since if $\phi^{\leftarrow}(a) = \{b,c\} \cup \dots$, then since $\phi\circ \phi^{\leftarrow} (a) = a$, we have $b = c$, by 1-1ness of $\phi$.  Iow, use the fact that $\phi$ is 1-1 to produce the fact that its reverse map is a function (not multi-valued, aka $\phi^{-1}$ returns singletons when provided with a singleton, etc).  You could use the notation $\phi^{-1} \equiv \phi^{\leftarrow}$ if you want, just know that there is a unique, well-defined map for $\phi$ also known as a right inverse.  Then we're almost done.  Now we've connected $\phi$ to the problem by defining $\phi^{-1}$ and showing that it's unique and well-defined.  Now

## define $\phi^* : A(S_1) \to A(S_2)$ as $\phi^*(f) = \phi f\phi^{-1}$.

Now show that $\phi^{-1}$ additionally is 1-1 and you have a composition of 1-1 maps which is 1-1.  $\phi^{-1}(a)  = \phi^{-1}(b) \implies \phi\phi^{-1}a = \phi\phi^{-1}b = a = b$.  So now we're done.

Comment: why do we need an inverse??

Comment: You don't need one, but one exists and it *is* unique and it answers the question.  Maybe there's a way to do it without an inverse, but that's another question.   Prove this first:  for an arbitrary map between any sets $f : X \to Y$, if $f$ is surjective a unique *left inverse* exists and if $f$ is injective then a unique *right inverse* exists.  Not $100\%$ sure about uniqueness but that's for you to prove.  Also prove that the converse of each of the two statements above is also true, iow, $f$ is injective $\iff$ a right inverse exists.  These two statements are used ALOT.

Comment: Crap, I got those two statements reversed: **$f$ is injective iff a left inverse exists** Before using the material above, make sure you undo that mistake.  So $\phi^*$ may end up now as $\phi^{-1} f \phi$ (or something...).

Comment: @Dan Donnelly From $\phi$ being a one-to-one mapping from $S_{1}$ to $S_{2}$, it does not follow that $\phi^{-1} \colon S_{2} \to S_{1}$ is a function, since we may have $\phi(S_{1}) \subsetneq S_{2}$. Your answer, fortunately, can easily be extended from a function on $\phi(S_{1})$ to a function on $S_{2}$, by, for example, defining $$
\phi^{*}(f)(s) =
\begin{cases} 
\phi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}(s), & \text{$s \in \phi(S_{1})$} \\
s, & \text{$s \notin \phi(S_{1})$}
\end{cases}
$$
where $s$ is an element of $S_{2}$.

Comment: Though the OP does not ask this, we can also prove that $\phi^{*} \colon A(S_{1}) \to A(S_{2})$, as extended in my comment above, is a monomorphism. In fact finding a mapping in the given problem which is both injective and a homomorphism is precisely exercise 21, Section 2.7, in Herstein's "Topics in Algebra" (2nd Edition).

Answer (score 0):

Given $\phi:S_1\rightarrow S_2$ and  $\psi:S_1\rightarrow S_1$ you are looking for a function  a function $\eta :S_2\rightarrow S_2$.

For sure, your $F(\psi)=\phi\circ g$ does not make sense..

You need $F(\psi)$ to be a function from  $S_2$ to $S_2$

i.e., given $s\in S_2$ you want to see what $F(\psi)(s)$ would be?

as you defined, $F(\psi)(s)=(\phi\circ \psi)(s)=\phi(\psi(s))$ does not make sense because $\psi(s)$ is not defined for $s\in S_2$ as $\psi\in A(S_1)$.

At present you only have  :

> a function whose image is in $S_2$ namely $\phi$ but not a function whose domain is $S_2$

So, only possible option is to consider inverse (I strongly feel there is no other way)

so, $\phi^{-1}:S_2\rightarrow S_1$

So, you took an element in $S_2$ and landed in $S_1$ but you want an element in $S_2$

So, only option is to search for a function which takes elements in $S_1$ and gives elements in $S_2$.

You do have $\phi:S_1\rightarrow S_2$ which takes elements in $S_1$ and produce an element in $S_2$ but that would not help you because you would then only get an identity function $\phi\circ \phi^{-1}$.

Another possible option is to consider $\phi\circ \psi$.. This takes elements in $S_1$ and gives elements in $S_2$

This should work I believe...

i.e., $F(\psi)=\phi\circ \psi\circ \phi^{-1}$

Rest is your part to check if it is one one...